# Adding shear to polygons

Tags: python, transform, polygon, shapes, data-augmentation

I'm trying to create a varied set of poylgons. To create this set I apply some transformations to regular polygons starting with [some rotations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALMpb.jpg). To add diversity I want to [add shear on each shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ME8Ez.jpg).

My issue is that my shear function [doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQ5SN.jpg) for some polygons which have been rotated to be inline with the x-axis (the scale of the outputs is way off).
More specifically it doesn't work for polygons with more than 4 sides that have been rotated to be inline with x axis, it does work for [rotated polygons with 4 or less sides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb8hZ.jpg).

My questions are does anyone know of a more robust method of adding shear to polygons?
If not, could you adivse on how I could make my current shear function more robust?

Here's the code to recreate the issue if anyone needs it:

*Switch between shear_dict and the commented out sl_shear_dict to see working and non working examples. 
The index/key for both dicts is the number of sides of the polygon.*

```
import math
from random import randint
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

#Generate regular polygons
def polygon(sides, radius=0.25, rotation=0, translation=None):
    one_segment = math.pi * 2 / sides
    x_coord = []
    y_coord = []
    if sides == 4:
        rotation = 0.785398
    for i in range(sides): 
        x = math.sin(one_segment * i + rotation) * radius
        y = math.cos(one_segment * i + rotation) * radius
        x_coord.append(x)
        y_coord.append(y)
    x_coord.append(x_coord[0])
    y_coord.append(y_coord[0]) 
    return x_coord,y_coord

#Generates stream facing polygons 
def streamfacing_polygon(sides, radius=0.25, rotation=0, translation=None):
    one_segment = math.pi * 2 / sides
    x_coord = []
    y_coord = []
    if sides == 3 or sides == 9:
        rotation = 0.523599
    if sides == 5 or sides ==7:
        rotation = -1.5708
    if sides == 6 or sides == 10:
        rotation = -1.5708
    if sides == 11:
        rotation = 0.139626 
    for i in range(sides): 
        x = math.sin(one_segment * i + rotation) * radius
        y = math.cos(one_segment * i + rotation) * radius
        x_coord.append(x)
        y_coord.append(y)
    x_coord.append(x_coord[0])
    y_coord.append(y_coord[0]) 
    return x_coord,y_coord

#Generate a set of polygons
def polygon_dict(max_num_sides,mode=None):
    polygon_dict = {}
    for i in range(3,max_num_sides):
        if mode == None:
            x,y =polygon(i)
            polygon_dict[i] = x,y
        elif mode == 'streamlined':
            x,y =streamfacing_polygon(i)
            polygon_dict[i] = x,y     
    return polygon_dict

shape_dict = polygon_dict(11)
sl_shape_dict = polygon_dict(11,'streamlined')


shear = np.identity(2)
def add_shear(shape_coord, low, high, key):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    shape_coord : x,y coordinates in a nested list(x,y) 
    low : Lowest shear value
    high : Highest shear value
    key : Number of sides of shape

    Returns
    -------
    sheared_poly : x,y coordinates of sheareed shapes
    shear_val : shear value used to produce this 

    """
    shear[0,1] = np.random.uniform(0.95, 1.05)
    shear[0,1] = np.random.uniform(low, high)
    print("\tusing shape_dict {} , shear {}".format(key, shear[0,1]))
    shear_val = shear[0,1]
    shape = shape_coord
    arf = np.asarray(shape)
    ar = arf.copy()

    tempar = ar.copy()
    arshear = np.dot(shear, ar).T

    if key < 0:
        min_original= min(arshear[:,0])
        min_shear = min(arf[:,0])
        miny_original= min(arshear[0,:])
        miny_shear= min(arf[0,:])

        for i in range(len(arshear)):
            arshear[i,0] = arshear[i,0]*(min_original/min_shear)
            arshear[i,1] = arshear[i,1]*(miny_original/min_shear)

        if 0:
            plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
            a, b = ar.T
            plt.scatter(a,b)
            plt.axis('equal')
            plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
            c, d = arshear.T
            plt.scatter(c,d)
            plt.axis('equal')
            #plt.show()
        sheared_poly = arshear.T

    else:
        maxx_original= max(arshear[:,0])
        maxx_shear = max(arf[:,0])
        maxy_original= max(arshear[0,:])
        maxy_shear= max(arf[0,:])

        for i in range(len(arshear)):
            arshear[i,0] = arshear[i,0]*(maxx_original/maxx_shear)
            arshear[i,1] = arshear[i,1]*(maxy_original/maxy_shear)
        if 0:
            plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
            a, b = ar.T
            plt.scatter(a,b)
            plt.axis('equal')
            plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
            c, d = arshear.T
            plt.scatter(c,d)
            plt.axis('equal')
            #plt.show()
        sheared_poly = arshear.T

    return sheared_poly, shear_val

#add shear to shape 
#switch between sl_shape_dict and shape_dict comments

#tri = sl_shape_dict[5]                  #doesn't work 
tri = shape_dict[5]                      #works
tri_sheared,shear_val =add_shear(tri, low =-0.4, high=-0.2, key=3 )
neg_tri_sheared,shear_val =add_shear(tri, low =-1.1, high=-0.9, key=3 )

#plotting 
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(tri_sheared[0], tri_sheared[1], marker='.', label='lo')
ax.plot(neg_tri_sheared[0], neg_tri_sheared[1], marker='.', label='hi')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.set_title('negative shear values')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')   
plt.show()
```

Comment: I have taken a quick look at your `add_shear` function and one possible reason for what you are experiences may be the divisions by `min_shear` (and maybe `max_shear`). Could you have very small values for `min_shear` when rotations are 0, pi, 2pi etc (i.e. `sin(theta)` is close to zero?) Have you checked the values of `min_shear` where you are getting erroneous results?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. That's exactly whats happening but I'm not sure how to guard against these extreme values from min/max_shear.

Comment: Why don't you compose an affine transformation matrix - that way you only use multiplications. See e.g https://medium.com/mlait/affine-transformation-image-processing-in-tensorflow-part-1-df96256928a

Comment: Thanks, this function looks promising. I've read the documentation and it says it should work with 2D arrays but I can't seem to get it going, any ideas? https://pastebin.com/0R1c0fqv

Comment: Unfortunately, I am working to a deadline at the moment and don't have the time to look into this in more detail. However, it is quite straightforward once you get going. Try the affine project from the pip repository - I am sure you will be able to use this straightaway: https://pypi.org/project/affine/

Comment: @KolaB no worries, you've been very helpful as it is. All the best with your project!